# Как разделить view на 3 равные части Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Имеется 2 view высотой 1px. Нужно просто разделить ими основное view на 3 равные части не используя StackView.В Storyboard. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно например путем смещения линий-вью от выравнивающих вертикально по центру констрейнтов путем выставления множителей (1/3 от центра в разные стороны)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]